# Monitoring JCS Cache Usage

Tags: caching, jcs

Our application is using JCS for caching frequently used data.

I wanted to know if JCS maintains(or can generate) any statistics having information like cache usage, cache misses, etc?

We recently decided to parallelise some job using multithreading. Although the threads will be working on different data, but they would be sharing the same cache (this I figured as they would be running in same JVM, and the JCS cache is a singleton class, please correct me if I am missing something here..).

So I need to analyse if we need to change the cache configuration for the added load.

Thanks a for your help!

Comment: There is a metadata facility in the the JCS known as JCS Bean.I have provided the link which explains in detail.Follow up if you have any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following web site gives a detail introduction,scroll down to the bottom of the page

[Click here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jcs/index.html)

If u want everything in a single go then use compCache.getStatistics(),refer to the API documentation for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There is a JSP available that shows you some of the information you are looking for like cache hits, misses, total memory used, etc.  You may have to edit it a little to fit into your project, but it's handy.

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/jcs/trunk/src/java/org/apache/jcs/admin/JCSAdmin.jsp